# the elusive wix installer and AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg dialog issue

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I'm building a WixUI_FeatureTree type WiX installer, but I am having a slight issue where AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg pops-up twice, even after I've agreed to the license.

The flow is simple, with an additional dialog that is displayed before the AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg (it's an additional consent agreement page).

The flow is: WelcomeDlg --> CustomEulaDlg --> AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg, and I have the option to go CustomizeDlg (Advanced) or VerifyReadyDlg (Install).

```
  <Publish Dialog="CustomEulaDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="CustomEulaDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg">1</Publish>      

  <Publish Dialog="AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg" Control="Advanced" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg" Control="Install" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg" Order="1">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="ServiceAccountDlg" Order="2">NOT Installed OR WixUI_InstallMode = "Change"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="3">Installed</Publish>
```

Once I'm at the AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg page and I click agree, I would like for the installed to proceed with the installation, as opposed to re-appearing again. Am I not validating something? Perhaps I'm missing a step in my VerifyReadyDlg.

Any help would be appreciated. WiX is a little convoluted.

**EDIT:**

```
Action 14:00:23: EulaDlg. Dialog created
MSI (c) (A4:5C) [14:00:23:760]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EULACHECK property. Its value is '1'.
Action 14:00:24: AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg. Dialog created
MSI (c) (A4:5C) [14:00:25:019]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding LicenseAccepted property. Its value is '1'.
Action ended 14:00:25: WelcomeDlg. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (A4:B8) [14:00:25:645]: Doing action: AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg
Action 14:00:25: AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg. 
Action start 14:00:25: AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg.
Action 14:00:25: AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 14:00:26: AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (A4:B8) [14:00:26:336]: Skipping action: MaintenanceWelcomeDlg (condition is false)
MSI (c) (A4:B8) [14:00:26:336]: Skipping action: ResumeDlg (condition is false)
MSI (c) (A4:B8) [14:00:26:336]: Doing action: ProgressDlg
Action 14:00:26: ProgressDlg. 
Action start 14:00:26: ProgressDlg.
Action 14:00:26: ProgressDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 14:00:26: ProgressDlg. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (A4:B8) [14:00:26:362]: Doing action: ExecuteAction
Action 14:00:26: ExecuteAction. 
Action start 14:00:26: ExecuteAction.
```

Comment: It's likely easier to debug what's going on by looking at the ControlEvent table of the finished MSI. Are there two AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg dialogs in your Dialog table?

Comment: @jbudreau thank you for the suggestion, i checked the install log, and it seems to be creating AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg (See my edit). p.s. there is only 1 AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg, bu before it is a custom dialog I call "EulaDlg", that gets presented before AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I'm adding this in case someone else runs into it.

I've been trying to show the `WelcomeDlg` before the `AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg`, but adding `NewDialog` to the the publish call was making it appear twice.  By ending the welcome dialog, the advanced EULA only appears once.

```
<!--This is after copying the WixUI_UIAdvanced.wxs and modifying-->

<!--Publish action added to close WelcomeDlg on Next rather than NewDialog the EULA-->
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="EndDialog" Value="Ignore">NOT Installed</Publish>

<!-- ... -->

<InstallUISequence>
    <!--Adding the 1 condition, makes it show even when not in maintenance-->
    <Show Dialog="WelcomeDlg" After="MigrateFeatureStates" >1</Show>
</InstallUISequence>
```

I'm still getting a feel for WiX/MSI, but from looking at [the source](https://github.com/AnalogJ/Wix3.6Toolset/blob/master/RC0-source/wix36-sources/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg.wxs), it looks like since they're calling the show before `ProgressDlg`, welcome shouldn't open it.

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg" Before="ProgressDlg">NOT Installed</Show>
</InstallUISequence>
```